# Access the same namespace from different libraries

Tags: c++, namespaces, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I build several libraries (static and dynamic ones) which all need to access a namespace containing namespace-global variables.

The functions for altering the variables are defined in one cpp file. If a function inside a library accesses one of those functions, it seems to create a local copy of the whole cpp file, including all variables (and maybe also functions). This means, every library accesses a variable at a different address, resultig in a mess, because the variables have to be shared by all libraries. How can I get around this?

The sourcecode, reduced to the essential:

```
//include.h
namespace myns {
    extern int vars;
}
```

.

```
//include.cpp
#include <myns/include.h>
namespace myns {
    int vars;
    void MyClass::setVars(int var) {
        vars = var;
    }
}
```

.

```
//myclass.h
namespace myns {
    class MyClass {
        void setVars(int var);
    }
}
```

.

```
//myclass.cpp.in
//This will be generated by CMake and then compiled into a library
#include <myns/@package@/myclass.h>
namespace myns {
    namespace @package@ {
        class __declspec(dllexport) MySubclass : public MyClass {
            MySubclass();
        }
        MySubclass::MySubclass() {
            setVar(@value@);
        }
    }
}
using namespace myns;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void exported_function() {
    new MySubclass();
}
```

Everytime the `exported_function()` is called, the `vars` variable would have a different address. Why does that happen? I need all library functions to access the *same* `vars` variable!

Answer (score 1):

Even though the language bears little resemblance to the alleged "C++", and even though the question is severely underspecified (what kind of libraries?), the problem is sufficiently well known that it's answerable.

In short, each Windows DLL has its own internal variables etc. (a Windows DLL is more akin to an executable than to a C++ library).

Note that standard C++ does not support dynamically loaded libraries except for a single cryptic little statement about global initialization order.

A solution is to put the shared state in its own DLL.

---

By the way, when you are providing setters and getters for a variable there is really little point in also making it directly accessible. That's asking for trouble. But then, using a global variable is, in the first place, also asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already suspected that there is an own scope for each DLL. Sorry for asking unclearly, but I didn't know how to properly break the problem down, since I was not even sure what was causing it. I am rewriting a project (originally written for Linux) for use on Windows.
What exactly do you mean with putting the state into a DLL? Wouldn't this worsen the problem since it would be an aditional DLL with its own scope?